# Copying 8 files from a folder to 40 other subfolders

Tags: powershell, copy, powershell-2.0

i tried to make a script which copies all (8 files) files from one folder into a specific subfolder of around ~40 folders...

i start like this with the * to copy all files out of that folder.
But of course it didn't work out like this :

The foldername with the * changes randomly and there is a subfolder called EmailTemplates which should get all my 8 files.

```
Copy-Item d:\www\example\*   -destination d:\example\2\*\EmailTemplates
```

Is there an easy solution ?
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this work for selecting the destination folder?

```
$destination = Get-ChildItem "D:\example\2" -Recurse | ? {
    $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.Name -eq "EmailTemplates"
  }
```

Otherwise you'll probably have to determine the destination like this:

```
$destination = Get-ChildItem "D:\example\2" |
  ? { $_.PSIsContainer } |
  % { Join-Path $_.FullName "EmailTemplates" } |
  ? { Test-Path -LiteralPath $_ } | Get-Item
```

Then copy the files like this:

```
Get-ChildItem "d:\www\example" | ? { -not $_.PSIsContainer } | % {
  Copy-Item $_.FullName $destination.FullName
}
```

Comment: Thanks, helped me alot, i made it a little different, but u helped me to do it